# How can I restrict jQuery UI connected lists drag and drop to single direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI [Connectedlist](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

Here drag and drop is working fine with both side from left to right and right to left.

How can I disable right to left ? It has to work only one way, from left to right.

I need also sorting to still work inside `ul` yellow items like in grey items.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, the correct way to do this is explained in my answer, the accepted answer does a lot more unnecessary processing. From my experience with ui sortable,  cancelling a sort after it was received even includes reversing DOM manipulation and stuff (internally in jQuery UI library).

Comment: @TJ in your answer, Dragging from left to right and dragging back the same `li` to the left that is not working.

Comment: Your question says *"It has to work only one way, from left to right"*. That clearly means no right to left. and it says *"I need also sorting to still work inside ul yellow items like in grey items."* - my answer does both, in the best way possible. Maybe what you asked is not what you wanted...

Comment: Yup. That is my mistake:( I did not asked clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cancel the drag event in the right list `sortable2` using **[receive](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive)** event in `sortable1` to prevent receiving any item from second list.

To drag grey `li`s back to the left side we will add helper class e.g `s2` that will identify the `sortable2` original items and cancel the drag only on them :

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
     receive: function(ev, ui) {
          if(ui.item.hasClass("s2"))
               ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
     }
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
         connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        receive: function(ev, ui) {
           if(ui.item.hasClass("s2"))
               ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight s2">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight s2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight s2">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight s2">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight s2">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I need one more sorting inside `ul` in yellow items like in grey items

Comment: In left side list we can sort the items move to top, bottom and inside anywhere with in that `ul` list where as that is not working in right side list.

Answer (score 2):

Currently your `connectWith` selector matches both the sortable, i.e it's a two way connection. If you only want one way connection from left to right, just connect the left sortable to right sortable using a more specific selector (`#sortable2`) than a common one:

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1").sortable({
      connectWith: "#sortable2"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortable2").sortable({}).disableSelection();
});
```

The demo below has the shorter code that does the same thing:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: "#sortable2"
   //----------^---------- #sortable2 connectWith #sortable2 has no effect
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The options you are looking for are cancel and update (s2 inspired by the post above), it will disable the drag on matched elements.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        cancel: ".ui-state-highlight, .s2",
        update: function( event, ui ) {ui.item.addClass("s2");}
    }).disableSelection();
});
```